# Sets of independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, finite-groups

So we're working in Z<sub>2</sub><sup>k</sup>, the group of bit-vectors of length k and componentwise addition modulo 2. Now I'm trying to make a function y<sub>j=1..?</sub>(v<sub>i</sub>) assigning elements of Z<sub>2</sub><sup>k</sup> to n vertices, such that every set of k vertices {v<sub>i</sub>}<sub>i=1..k</sub> gets assigned a set of k independent vectors {y<sub>j</sub>(v<sub>i</sub>)}<sub>i=1..k</sub> for at least one j. I think it should be possible in n assignments (j=1..n), but I can only construct it for small k or n..

Does anyone know how this problem is called (so I can search for literature concerning it), or even better, how to solve it?

Thank you so much!
Karl

Comment: Most of your notation appears as boxes () for me. Can you use LaTeX instead?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Thanks for the suggestion; now everything is plain ASCII and html

Comment: No worries. For future reference, you can put notation inside dollar signs for it to be 'mathified', e.g. `$v_2$` is rendered as $v_2$ and `$\{y_j(v_i)\}_{i\dots k}$` is rendered as $\{y_j(v_i)\}_{i\dots k}$.

Comment: I take it by "independent" you mean "linearly independent over the field of 2 elements" so I'm adding the linear algebra tag (and removing the algebraic groups tag, which has a specialized meaning). But I could be wrong.

Comment: No, you're right :)

Comment: This is very hard to read, by "a function" you actually mean a number of functions indexed by j and you chose "?" as name of this key number?